# Making a neat orthonormal basis with one vector being: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{77}}\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 6 & 5 \end{pmatrix}^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to make an orthonormal basis, where one vector is:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{77}}\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\
6 \\
5
\end{pmatrix}$

After that I need to do a lot of other calculations (by hand ... ). This is part of a Schur decomposition. I'm trying to get a little neat orthonormal basis here as otherwise I'm making thousands of mistakes.

By just using gram-schmidt I get a very ugly basis. Is there a way to do this a little bit more sophisticated ? For example, I would like to call $t=\frac{1}{\sqrt {77}}$. And having all basisvectors of the form $$u=
t\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $a,b,c$ is not some kind of exotic $-\frac{\sqrt{61}}{\sqrt{4697}}$ kind of thing.

Comment: It's difficult to answer a question based entirely on aesthetics.  I would recommend forgetting about the $\frac{1}{77}$ for now, and building an orthogonal basis out of $(4,6,5)$, and two other basis elements of your choice.  You can normalize them at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call your vector $u_1$. Let $v = (1,0,0)$. Then let $u_2$  be a unit vector in the direction of $u_1 \times v$. Then let $u_3 = u_2 \times u_1$. Then $u_1$, $u_2$, $u_3$ will be orthonormal, and the numbers should not be too bad.

The choice of $v$ is fairly arbitrary, of course. It should give you fairly nice numbers, but other choices might be even nicer.

**Edit**:

I felt guilty about not doing the computations myself, and I was interested to see how different choices of $v$ affected the result. I don't claim that it's optimal, but, among the obvious choices, I found that $v = (1,1,1)$ works best. It gives the orthonormal basis:

$$u_1 = (4,6,5)/\sqrt{77}$$

$$u_2 = (1,1,-2)/\sqrt{6}$$

$$u_3 = (17,-13,2)/\sqrt{462}$$

In general, the trick is to choose $v$ so that it has simple components (zeros and ones) and so that it is roughly parallel to $u_1$. This causes $u_1 \times v$ to have small magnitude. Note this is exactly the *opposite* of what you would do if you were performing these calculations in floating point arithmetic on a computer. In a computer program, you would choose a $v$ that is nearly perpendicular to $u_1$.

Comment: According to my calculations $u_3$ and $u_4$ are orthogonal but not normal. The best I can come up with is the vectors $(4,6,5),(5,0,4),(-24,41,30)$. The last one has length $\sqrt{3157}$. I think I just should do the calculations for the schur decomposition... But it such a mess !

Comment: Well, $u_3$ and $u_1$ are unit vectors, and they are orthogonal. So $u_4$ should be another unit vector that is orthogonal to both of them. Use Mathematica, or Matlab, or even Excel. Doing this by hand is asking for grief and frustration. That's why I didn't do it myself :-)

Comment: Your calculation is wrong. You should get $(4,6,5)$, $(0,5,-6)$, $(61,-24,-20)$.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a variant of the Euclidean algorithm on $\{4,6,5\}$ to produce $0$ to get a nice second vector. A quick ad-hoc calculation gives:

- $1 = 1 \cdot 6 - 1 \cdot 5$
- $1 = 1 \cdot 5 - 1 \cdot 4$
- $0 = 1 \cdot 1 - 1 \cdot 1 = 1 \cdot 4 - 2 \cdot 5 + 1 \cdot 6$

So we know $(4,6,5)$ is orthogonal to $(1,1,-2)$.

A more systematic method would be to use lattice reduction on the orthogonal complement to $(4,6,5)$. First do integer row reduction:

$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & 4
\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 6
\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 5
\end{array} \right) \mapsto \left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
-1 & 0 & 1 & 1
\\ 6 & 1 & -6 & 0
\\ 5 & 0 & -4 & 0
\end{array} \right)$$

(you may, of course, get a different matrix) Then take the two rows that give zero and lattice reduction gives

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & -1 & 2
\\ 3 & -2 & 0
\end{array} \right)$$

(I used the LLL command in sage) So $(-1,-1,2)$ is the shortest integer vector perpendicular to $(4,6,5)$. Then you could take the cross product to get a third.

The nice thing about the lattice reduction approach is that it generalizes to higher dimensions. If you already have $m$ orthogonal vectors in an $n$-dimensional space, you can do row reduction to get a basis for the integer orthogonal complement to your $m$ vectors, and do LLL to get a short one, and take that as your $(m+1)$-th vector.

Of course, the later vectors will probably be relatively large. Trying to make them *all* short is a much harder problem, I think, and I'm not sure how to go about doing that. My first instinct would be to take *any* orthogonal vectors, then try some sort of simulated annealing optimization procedure to find smaller sets of orthogonal vectors.